# Returning a struct containing a local pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct

Is it valid to return a struct containing a local array in C?

for example:

```
// Define a string type
typedef struct {
    char* c_str;
} string;

// Function to append 2 strings
string string_append(string str1, const string str2) {

    // Create a local array
    char buffer[strlen(str1.c_str) + strlen(str2.c_str) + 1];

    strcpy(buffer, str1.c_str);
    strcat(buffer, str2.c_str);

    // Store a pointer to the local array in a struct
    string ret = { buffer };

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    string str1 = { "hello" };
    string str2 = { "goodbye" };
    string str3 = string_append(str1, str2);
}
```

Will the contents of `str3` be valid after performing `string_append`?

Comment: Your structure **does not** contain an array: it contains a pointer. Check section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com) for more info about the differences between array and pointer.

Comment: I will clarify the question.  What I am asking is would the contents of the array pointed to by the struct be compromised?

Comment: They will not be valid. You can't do this.

Comment: Well thats disappointing...

Comment: It has a good reason not to be.

Comment: You can't alloc a `char[]` using `[]` with a variable (value calculed at run time) size. You must use `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` (`new` if you use C++).

Comment: Using [] with a variable is valid syntax in C, look it up.  It compiles and works.  Returning a local pointer however is not valid... I guess I will have to settle on using malloc and free.  I was trying to implement something using only stack variables so people using it would be less likely to create memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as noted in the comments, you can't do this. But *why*?

The answer is that your code

```
char buffer[strlen(str1.c_str) + strlen(str2.c_str) + 1];
```

is allocating *automatic* storage, which is to say, it's created as part of the stack that also contains the return address for the function, and the arguments. So, when you return from the function, the space allocated may or may not be corrupted by the time you try to use it -- but it probably will be.

Answer (score 3):

Once your function returns, the contents of `buffer` are undefined. If you want to create something inside your function that can exist outside the function, you need to allocate it with `malloc` (or something equivalent).

Comment: If I return a variable allocated using malloc how can I easily ensure anyone using my function will know it will need to be freed?

Comment: @tjwrona1992: By providing nicely written documentation.

Comment: @alk: I still feel like returning a malloced variable from a function is just a memory leak waiting to happen in the hands of some poor inexperienced developer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `buffer` character array is created inside the function. The default storage class of variables created inside function is `Automatic`.

That means, your variable will be created as a part of the stack. However, when function returns and control goes to the calling function, that stack will be soon modified if in case, your calling function calls another function. For example, if you call `printf()` after the `string_append()` function. The stack created for `printf()` will overwrite the location pointed by your `char *c_str pointer of string str3`. And it will print some garbage values.

Give it a try.